# Error receiving data from a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, types

i have a WCF with several methods: GetAccount, UpdateAccount, DeleteAccont and ListAccount, the first three work well, but ListAccount doesn't.
I get an error:

[image: Error]

The ListAccount return a List of Account:

```
[DataContract]
public class Account
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private AccountType accountType;
    private Account upperAccount;
    private Dictionary<Business, double> porc;

    public Account()
    {
        porc = new Dictionary<Business, double>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public AccountType AccountType
    {
        get { return accountType; }
        set { accountType = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Account UpperAccount
    {
        get { return upperAccount; }
        set { upperAccount = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<Business, double> Porc
    {
        get { return porc; }
        set { porc = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}


[DataContract]
public enum AccountType : byte
{
    [EnumMember]
    [Description("Account Type One")]
    One = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    [Description("Account Type Two")]
    Two = 1,
}

[DataContract]
public enum Business : byte
{
    [EnumMember]
    [Description("Business One")]
    BusinessOne = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    [Description("Business Two")]
    BusinessTwo = 1,
}
```

One observation, the list contains 45 items.

Any help will be well received. Thanks

Comment: What does the OperationContract look like for ListAccount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely hitting one of the quotas in WCF - the way to find out for sure is to [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) at the server, and look at the traces which will contain an exception telling why the server disconnected the client. Without this information there's just a bunch of guesswork we can do: maybe you're hitting the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota (can increase using the `<dataContractSerializer`> endpoint or service behavior; maybe the graph has a cycle and you need to enable `preserveObjectReferences` to deal with it, etc. But only with the traces we'll be able to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks, enabling tracing i found the error. The problem was an enum not defined. The inner exception: "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter GetListAccount".

Answer (score 0):

Is your ListAccount method throwing any errors? Rather than returning a list try using the list's .ToArray method and return an Account[]. I assume your GetAccount method returns a single Account object, which means it is serializable.